# method description in flex code assist in flex builder

Tags: apache-flex

I am new to flex and am using flex builder 3 , many a times code assist shows a lot of function but i am not sure what these functions do. How can i configure flex builder so that it also shows descriptions of the methods  like the one we get in java.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think Flash Builder 4 added the feature to show the ASDocs of a particular method along with code hinting.

There is nothing you can do to make this show up in Flex Builder 3, though.